# How to handle push notifications for users with high activity

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, push

I need to implement a push notifications for a large system.

The system have users that would receive notifications very often, so just the push could generate a significant network traffic. How can I optimize it?

In order to give a more concrete example imagine Twitter's push system.

If we send a push to notify a user when one of his message gets retwitted:

If Lady Gaga posts a tweet, and it receives 6k retweets, and we send a push with every retweet, assuming 1KB per push notification, Lady Gaga will get 6MB+ consumed from her data plan.

What are the techniques that can be applied to this cases?

Comment: Try PushBots https://pushbots.com/

Comment: Batch the pushes? So instead of sending 1 per retweet, you could send a single push after a certain period that says "347 people retweeted your message"